# pyplot clipping data with incorrect yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize, axis, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to plot two lines with different yaxis on the same figure, but the yaxis won't scale out enough to show the full dataset.

I've tried using axis.autoscale(), axis.set_ylim(), axis.axis()... but none of them set the yaxis correctly, even when the bounds are explicitly given.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_result(acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss=None):
    fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)

    ax1.plot(acc, 'g')
    ax1.autoscale(axis='y')

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(loss, 'r')
    if val_loss is not None: ax2.plot(val_loss, 'r--')
    ax2.autoscale(axis='y')

    fig.tight_layout()

plot_result(acc, val_acc, loss)
```

[output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr856.png)

I expect both lines to cover the full 30 epochs. 
strangly, when I write `fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)` at the top instead, it plots correctly (but with empty subplot on the right).

[correct axis, but unwanted subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd3vp.png)

Answer (score -1):

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss=np.random.rand(20),np.random.rand(20),np.random.rand(20),np.random.rand(0)

def plot_result(acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))

    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.plot(acc)
    plt.plot(val_acc)
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.plot(loss)
    plt.plot(val_loss)
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
plot_result(acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss)
```

[image: output]

Comment: sorry, this doesn't address the problem. I was already able to get the correct plots with two subplots. the error occurs when there is only one plot.